# logfile causes permission error in django application deployed on apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I have deployed a `Django 1.3.1 app` on `apache2` in my machine using `mod_wsgi`.I used to log some values in the app using python logging module and these were written to a mylog.txt file in the application base directory.However I deleted this file and commented out every log() call in my code.In the django standalone server the app runs without any problem.But when I start the app in apache,I get this apache log entry

```
[Sat Mar 31 09:34:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught IOError while rendering: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/me/dev/python/django/myapp/mylog.txt'
```

I cannot understand why this happens ,since I commented out every log related line in the code and even the variable which tells the logfile's name in settings.py

I tried clearing the cache..but even that didn't help

can someone help me figure this out?

The module details are as below

```
Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.6.5 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are the unix/linux permissions on your mylog.txt file?

`ls -la /home/me/dev/python/django/myapp/mylog.txt` should show the unix/linux perms.  Can you paste the results of this command? (update it in your question above if possible)

Apache2 user on your system (depending on which linux distro of if you use Mac) are most likely 'www-data' or 'http'.  You will need to make sure that mylog.txt has the correct unix/linux owner and the correct permissions mode so that apache2 can write into this log file.

Comment: OK that did it..I changed file permissions and now it doesn't complain

Comment: thanks for the help..however,now I get another error.I am using matplotlib in my app..The new error says `'/home/damon' is not a writable dir; you must set /home/damon/.matplotlib to be a writable dir.  You can also set environment variable MPLCONFIGDIR to any writable directory where you want matplotlib data stored ..` Is it safe to change permission of home directory to 774?

Comment: it's better not to. are you using virtualenv and pip to install your dependencies such as matplotlib? if not, you should really do that as it will help prevent all sorts of weird permissions problems like these from cropping up.

Comment: That explains it. `python setup.py install` does not always give you the correct perms.  Use pip. And virtualenv. It's going to take anything between 1 hour to 8 hours for you to get familiar with virtualenv and pip; but trust me, it's a worthwhile investment for all your future python projects.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem in Webpy+Apache. And I changed the Apache logs directory owner to Apache user then the problem solved.